# How to place images in latex so that it doesnt consume extra blank space?

Tags: graphics, formatting

I am writing a report in which when I place an image it is creating lots of blank space and the formatting looks bad. This is how it looks like

[image]

I have used the following latex command for this

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,  height=10cm]{Image.png}
\end{center}
```

But I want something like this

[image]

Here I have used the following code

```
\lipsum[1]\par
{\centering\vspace{10pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,  height=10cm]{Image.png}
\captionof{figure}{caption of figure\label{fig:img1}}
\vspace{10pt}
\par}
\lipsum[2]
```

But u can see that since I have used lipsum, it is inserting gibberish text in it, and making it look like what I desired. But how to do this without lipsum? Any help will be great. Thank you.

After edit suggested by @Mico in the comments it is like this

[image]

The code used,

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Image.png} 
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Put the graphic in a figure environment so that it can float.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sir can you please tell me the command, I am new to latex and cannot get how to do the same. It will be very helpful

Comment: Try replacing `\begin{center} \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,   height=10cm]{Image.png} \captionof{figure}{...} \end{center}` with `\begin{figure}[htbp] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Image.png} \caption{...}\end{figure}`.

Comment: @Mico still not working

Comment: @Turing101 - Sorry, but "still not working" is an unusable piece of information. *What exactly* isn't working? Do you receive error and or warning messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: @Mico No warning messages, but still the same problem. I have attached the picture of what is happening after your edit, in my question.

Comment: You need to post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem.  Otherwise we are just guessing...

Comment: the reason you have large white space in your last image is that you have prevented whatever is at the top of the next page going on this or floating. so as the problem is on code not shown it is hard to help

Comment: Wrap the figure in an fbox command. You might have extra qhite spacing from when you saved the figure. If that's the case, you can crop it directly from invludegraphics